# Adding Bootstrap Glyphicon to jQuery UI Dialog Buttons

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, glyphicons

I have looked long and hard, but cant seem to find any good documentation on how to do this.

I can add classes like this:

```
$('#element').dialog({
  buttons:{
    "yes":{
      text:'Yes',
      class:'test'
    },
    "no":{
      text:'No',
    }
});
```

This does not allow me to add a span tag.

I tried:

```
.test:before {
    content:"\e105";
}
```

But that just adds a little block on top of the text:

[image]

I've also tried injecting the span, which I really don't want to land up doing because it feels very 'hacky'.

```
$('.ui-dialog-buttonpane')
.find('button:contains("Yes")')
.removeClass('ui-button-text-only')
.prepend('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-export"></span>')
```

This gives me:

[image]

Is there any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The villain seems to be:

```
.ui-icon {
  display: block;
  text-indent: -99999px; /* THIS GUY HERE! */
  overflow: hidden;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

But you don't want to get rid of him completely, since it might affect the icons present in jQuery UI widgets.

So you can overwrite it just for the elements to which we apply `glyphicon` class like:

```
.ui-icon.glyphicon {
  text-indent: initial;
}
```

Now, to apply these glyphicon classes, use the [icons](http://api.jqueryui.com/button/#option-icons) option of jQuery button widget like:

```
$(function () {
  $("#dialog").dialog({
     buttons: [{
        text: "Ok",
        icons: {
            primary: "glyphicon glyphicon-export"
        },
        click: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }]
  });
});
```

This gives me:

[image]

Comment: This does not work on IE11, firefox and chrome are fine. The text-indent is still applied, even with !important.

Comment: @SeanThorburn that is an IE specific issue, you might want to ask a different question asking why `!important` doesn't work in IE11...

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add

```
.test { 
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings'; 
}
```

Comment: Any suggestion on getting the icon in the same line and not above?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide an ID to the button and add glyphicon through css

```
   "yes":{
          id:'idYes',
          text:'Yes',
          class:'test'
        },
        "no":{
          id: 'idNo',
          text:'No',
        }
```

CSS for adding

```
#idYes:before{
  color:green;
  content:"\e170";
}
```

Similarly for the other button. You can refer to the [Bootstrap glyphicon cheatsheet](http://glyphicons.bootstrapcheatsheets.com/) for icon code